# In UNIX find and list file_names consisting number and date, if greater than a specific number

Tags: unix, unix-socket

I have many files in unix system that match the pattern `'ZLOG_106475_20170517.zip'` 
where, `106475` denotes the id within the filename.

> I want to fetch the names of all such files having id greater than a
>   specific no e.g. `106171`

And push the names into a `.lst` list file in unix.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash with a for construct

```
for file in ZLOG_*.zip; do
    [[ -e $file ]] || continue    # check file exist
    id=${file#ZLOG_}   # remove prefix
    id=${id%%_*}       # remove suffix
    if ((id>106171)); then
        echo "$file"
    fi
done >list.txt
```

Comment: Thanks.. let me try it.